# iframes in Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, napili, lightning-community

Do Lightning components support iframes? I tried putting an iframe tag on a component and nothing displayed. I am aware that you can host a visualforce page from Lightning and have an iframe in that although not recommended by Salesforce. My scenario is to display iframe content in a customer community using the Napili template and I was thinking of using a custom Lightning component as a means of doing so. Trying to put an iframe directly into the 'Rich Content Editor' component does not work. Possibly the 'force:canvasApp' Lightning component could be an alternative. Any advice on the feasiblity/right direction on this appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a sample code? I've played around with iFrames, but it's not really the most optimal route to go. I've also used 'force:canvasApp' on a Lightning Component and there were some bugs that prevented a page to display on Community Builder.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible at the current time (Spring 17 Release) to use a simple iframe to wrap a Visualforce page. This requires myDomain to be enabled in your org because it is required for Lightning Components and seems to hard code the orgid.

It seems to not have much in the way of documentation on the SF Developer site.

For a Napili template community I have used the following

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <iframe src="https://orgname--flex.cs82.visual.force.com/apex/lightning_calendar" width="100%" height="400px;" />
</aura:component>
```