# Is it possible to load Iframe from a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe

I need to load Iframe from a lightning component in the community site( Napili template). Once I load Iframe from a lightning component I'm getting following error.

> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-src https: mailto:".

How can I load Iframe from a Lightning component?

Comment: please can you include the relevant sections of the lightning component in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, and there are several posts addressing this question on the forum:

[Is it posible to add iframe directly in lightning components?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166612/is-it-posible-to-add-iframe-directly-in-lightning-components)

[iframes in Lightning components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153244/iframes-in-lightning-components)

However, the error seems to be in relation to the CSP directive, you can manage the CSP settings under critical updates as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/security_csp_stricter.htm).

> Stricter CSP is enabled by default for sandboxes and Developer Edition
>   orgs that have previously enabled the “Enable Lightning LockerService
>   Security” critical update. For all other sandboxes and Developer
>   Edition orgs, stricter CSP is disabled by default.
>
> To disable stricter CSP:
>
> From Setup, enter Critical Updates in the Quick Find box, and then
>   select Critical Updates.
>
> To “Disable Stricter Content Security Policy
>   for Lightning Components”, click Disable. Refresh your browser page to
>   proceed with stricter CSP Disabled.

(changed enable for disable within the text)